# Editing Django models, with existing objects?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

Is there a way to edit an existing Django model class (adding/removing fields), and make the changes apply to previously created objects in the (SQLite) database?

For instance:

```
class Mod(models.Model):
    usrID = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(default="")
```

And in a later stage, after there are a large amounts of objects of named class instantiated, change to:

```
class Mod(models.Model):
    usrID = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(default="")
    description = models.TextField(default="")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use a database migration tool, one of the most popular database migration for Django is [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).